# How to filter data properties coming from API in PHP?

Tags: php

I have this data coming from an API, the tmdb api, and I want to create an api to filter the data and expose just the properties I need. In this case I just want my endpoint to expose id, title, and overview and nothing else. How can filter these properties with PHP in order to get and expose just the properties I need?

```
"results:[{
"vote_count": 779,
"id": 420817,
"video": false,
"vote_average": 7.2,
"title": "Aladdin",
"popularity": 476.676,
"poster_path": "/3iYQTLGoy7QnjcUYRJy4YrAgGvp.jpg",
"original_language": "en",
"original_title": "Aladdin",
"genre_ids": [
12,
14,
10749,
35,
10751
],
"backdrop_path": "/v4yVTbbl8dE1UP2dWu5CLyaXOku.jpg",
"adult": false,
"overview": "A kindhearted street..."
}],
```

The expected result should be:
myapi.com/api

```
"results:[{
"id": 420817,
"title": "Aladdin",
"overview": "A kindhearted street ..."
}],
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering JSON data with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763608/filtering-json-data-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the array like this:

```
function myFilter($result) {

    $filtered_array = array();

    foreach($result as $movie) {

        $filtered_movie = array();

        $filtered_movie['id'] = $movie['id'];
        $filtered_movie['title'] = $movie['title'];
        $filtered_movie['overview'] = $movie['overview'];

        array_push($filtered_array, $filtered_movie);

    }

    return $filtered_array;
}
```

Just pass the unfiltered array to the function and you'll get the filtered one back.

**EDIT:**

If your data is in JSON format you will need to use `json_decode()` to turn it in to an array in PHP. And if you want to return it as JSON then use `json_encode()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = json_decode($data);
$results = $json->results;

$results= array_map(function($r){
   return ["id" => $r->id, "title" => $r->title, "overview" => $r->overview]
}, $results)

echo json_encode($results);
```